# Angularjs translate in code-behind

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-translate

I am struggling with binding enum class to SELECT statement.

Given TypeScript definition:

```
enum SearchCriteria {
  expensive = 0,
  cheap = 1,
  interesting = 2,
  newest = 3
}
```

and the usage:

```
<div id="searchResultSort">
            {{'sort' | translate}}:
            <select 
                    ng-model=" options.selectedCriteria">
                <option value="0"> {{'sortByExpensive' | translate}}</option>
                <option value="1"> {{'sortByCheap' | translate}}</option>
                <option value="2"> {{'sortByInteresting' | translate}}</option>
                <option value="3"> {{'sortByNewest' | translate}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Now there are few problems with this code:

1) Enum values are hardcoded

2) Default value functionality is not working - I tracked this bug down to the way angularjs handles this scenario. It uses comparision === thus "0" !== 0.
[Initial ng-model value not set in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201628/angularjs-initial-ng-model-value-not-set-in-select)

I wouldn't mind solving this problem by creating new array in controller that has two properties: {translatedVal, enumId}.

The problem is, how do I keep this "translatedVal" sync with the real translation?

```
sortingOptions: [
    {
        val: SuperSearch.Repository.Model.SearchCriteria.cheap,
        translation: bindAndInterpolateLanguage('languageKey')
    },
```

Using angular-translate.

Comment: Have you considered using `ng-options` (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) instead? That will give you the ability to bind the values directly to numbers (1 vs "1")

Answer (score 1):

This is the best what I have found and still using in my projects for binding values to select component. Here I have a department list.

```
<select data-ng-model="selectedDepartment"   
data-ng-options="dept.DepartmentId as dept.Title for dept in departments"   
data-ng-change="onDepartmentChange()" />
```

You can access as well as manipulate the value of "selectedDepartment" anytime.

Hope it give some idea to tackle with the problem you are facing.

Comment: I need to incorporate translation somehow with this

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa you can use the `translate` filter in the `ng-options` to change what is displayed as the option label. I have edited Manish's answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

if you declare the values manually, then try this way

```
  <select class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="selectedSearchCriteria" ng-change="changeTenant(this.selectedSearchCriteria)" required ng-options="i.ToString() for i in SearchCriteria"></select> 

var SearchCriteria=[{
          "expensive":0},
          {"cheap" : 1},
          {"interesting" : 2},
          {"newest" : 3}]        
         $scope.selectedSearchCriteria = SearchCriteria[0];
```

If you get a values from server side using ajax call , Then try this below way

```
 <select class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="selectedSearchCriteria" ng-change="changeTenant(this.selectedSearchCriteria)" required ng-options="i.ToString() for i in SearchCriteria"></select> 

             $http.get(URL)
               .success(function (response) {
                   $scope.SearchCriteria= response;
                   $scope.selectedSearchCriteria = response[0];
                   $scope.$apply();
               });
```